# How to find origin of a variable or function in a large visual basic project

Tags: vb6

I have large visual basic 6 project with 50 forms and many modules. When i open a form i found some variables/functions used in that form is not  originated there. Then how can i find out where it is first written without going through all codes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Open the project in the IDE.  Find an occurrence of the variable, function, etc. of interest, right-click and choose *Definition*.  This should take you there.

Comment: Keyboard shortcut for this is [Shift]+[F2].

Answer (score 6):

The Goto definition SHIFT + F2 is what I use when working in a smaller project. However, if you want some real power, download and install [MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) or Agent Ransack. I personally use [MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) and it has some fantastic features for VB6 such as finding occurrences of variables, methods, etc plus a plethora more features that I know you'll find extremely useful.

[MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) is also free for use and you can donate if you wish.

Comment: +1. Slight quibble: "goto definition" is useful in projects of any size, large or small. But +1 for MZ Tools, *the* essential free add-in for VB6. BTW I edited your answer to add links.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose what I meant to say was that if you have larger projects you may have a mix of early and late bound references and it is much harder to navigate to definitions. With MZ Tools it will find all references based upon text matching as well which the IDE cannot determine. This is similar in fashion to how ReSharper works in .NET.

Comment: The MZ Tools "find all references" is marvellous. But I don't quite understand your comment. Late-binding means your variables are dimensioned `As Object`. It has no effect on the behaviour of the "go to definition" command in the IDE, which will take you to the variable declaration line. The "go to definition" command doesn't go to references. It, well, goes to definitions.

Comment: Simply stated: With MZ Tools you can use "Find" and it can find anything. With a late bound reference the IDE does not have ability to jump to a particular method but would if it was early bound. MZ Tool will simply find all occurences of it and let you click to jump there. This is similar to ReSharper.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> is working for me even in large project.

Answer (score 0):

They are probably globally scoped variables. Look for a file named global.bas (or any file named with a .bas extension) and see if the variables are declared in there.

Functions can also be declared at a global scope in .bas files as well. They were generally referred to as "modules" to differentiate them from the .cls files VB6 adopted in its own flavor of object programming. You'll also find Win32 API function declarations in there...

Comment: Actually they're *static modules* and unlike most other module types everything in them has a single copy that stays statically loaded for the life of the program.  An exception is thread-local storage "copies" when using a multithreaded ActiveX EXE (each thread gets a copy of the static data, though not the code).

Comment: All true, but the OP was just trying to find a file where the variable and functions declarations resided. Just tried to keep it simple...don't think at this point he's diving too far into thread-local storage in a VB6 app :)

Answer (score -1):

[This may be helpful to you](http://rhondatipton.net/2008/01/05/useful-visual-studio-search-tool/). From what I can find VS doesn't have a project search feature. If I'm misinformed and it does in fact have one, use that instead.

Comment: VB6 isn't supported by Visual Studio, it uses its own IDE.

Comment: -1. Like Deanna said, this answer is for a different IDE (Visual Studio 2010?). The OP wants advice on VB6